# How to set trigger 'onOpen' on a spreadsheet instead of a sheet? (Focus last row)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-api

I want to focus the last row on a specific sheet (or if possible on every one of them) so here is my function triggered by `onOpen` on the sheet:

```
function FocusLastRows() {
var spsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spsheet.getSheetByName("Usuelle_2013");
var rowInt = sheet.getLastRow();
var colInt = sheet.getLastColumn();
var range = sheet.getRange(rowInt, colInt)
sheet.setActiveRange(range)
}
```

This event works but if my first loaded sheet is different from the one I want it to focus on it just teleports to the other sheet. Best will be to set an `.onOpen` on the spreadsheet.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good alternative for it. It's custom menu with function link to it.

```
    //Pierre-luc Des. Script

//Build your menu 
function setMenu() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menubuttons = [ {name: "Dernière ligne usuelle", functionName:  "GOTOLastRow}];
    ss.addMenu("Outils", menubuttons);
} 

function GOTOLastRow() { 
var spsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var currentTime = new Date();
var sheet = spsheet.getSheetByName("Usuelle_" + currentTime.getFullYear());
var rowInt = sheet.getLastRow();
var colInt = sheet.getLastColumn();
var range = sheet.getRange(rowInt, colInt);
sheet.setActiveRange(range);

}
```

Now i will have a clickable menu "Outils" which will let me do the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather inelegant, but perhaps try just checking whether the activated sheet is the target sheet? Something like this:

```
function FocusLastRows() {
var spsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spsheet.getSheetByName("Usuelle_2013");
  if (sheet == spsheet) {
    var rowInt = sheet.getLastRow();
    var colInt = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var range = sheet.getRange(rowInt, colInt);
    sheet.setActiveRange(range);
  }
}
```

The [Google Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) seems to indicate that you'll need custom libraries to get any other trigger events than the ones provided, and I'm not sure if it's even in-principle possible to trigger only when a certain specific sheet is activated.

I figure checking the sheet with if comparisons is the next-simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I understand your idea, but it will only works if the target sheet is the good one because onOpen only triggers once.

Comment: See my alternative and tell me what you think !!